fatal error: pico/cyw43_arch.h: No such file or directory
I am giving my first steps coding a Pico W in C. I am following the instructions from here. I am working in a Raspberry Pi 4. I am able to build the examples, but now I want to build my own standalone project. This is my directory structure:
blink_so_complicated/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── pico_sdk_import.cmake
└── src
    └── main.c

This is the content of CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# initialize the SDK based on PICO_SDK_PATH
# note: this must happen before project()
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

project(blink_so_complicated)

# initialize the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()

# rest of your project
add_executable(blink_so_complicated
    src/main.c
)

# Add pico_stdlib library which aggregates commonly used features
target_link_libraries(blink_so_complicated pico_stdlib)

# create map/bin/hex/uf2 file in addition to ELF.
pico_add_extra_outputs(blink_so_complicated)

This is the content of main.c:
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/cyw43_arch.h"

#define LED_DELAY_MS 100

// Perform initialisation
int pico_led_init(void) {
    // For Pico W devices we need to initialise the driver etc
    return cyw43_arch_init();
}

// Turn the led on or off
void pico_set_led(bool led_on) {
    // Ask the wifi "driver" to set the GPIO on or off
    cyw43_arch_gpio_put(CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN, led_on);
}

int main() {
    int rc = pico_led_init();
    hard_assert(rc == PICO_OK);
    while (true) {
        pico_set_led(true);
        sleep_ms(LED_DELAY_MS);
        pico_set_led(false);
        sleep_ms(LED_DELAY_MS);
    }
}

Then I do mkdir build, cd build, then:
liomessi@afa:~/code/RPi_pico_tests/blink_C/build $ cmake .. -DPICO_SDK_PATH=../../../pico-sdk/ -DPICO_BOARD=pico_w
PICO_SDK_PATH is /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk
Target board (PICO_BOARD) is 'pico_w'.
Using board configuration from /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/src/boards/include/boards/pico_w.h
Defaulting platform (PICO_PLATFORM) to 'rp2040' based on PICO_BOARD setting.
-- Defaulting build type to 'Release' since not specified.
Defaulting compiler (PICO_COMPILER) to 'pico_arm_cortex_m0plus_gcc' since not specified.
Configuring toolchain based on PICO_COMPILER 'pico_arm_cortex_m0plus_gcc'
Defaulting PICO_GCC_TRIPLE to 'arm-none-eabi'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
Build type is Release
CMake Warning at /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/tools/Findpicotool.cmake:28 (message):
  No installed picotool with version 2.0.0 found - building from source

  It is recommended to build and install picotool separately, or to set
  PICOTOOL_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH to a common directory for all your SDK
  projects
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/tools/CMakeLists.txt:138 (find_package)
  /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/src/cmake/on_device.cmake:33 (pico_init_picotool)
  /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeLists.txt:57 (pico_add_dis_output)
  /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeLists.txt:101 (pico_define_boot_stage2)


Downloading Picotool
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.11.2") found components: Interpreter 
TinyUSB available at /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
BTstack available at /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/lib/btstack
cyw43-driver available at /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/lib/cyw43-driver
Pico W Bluetooth build support available.
lwIP available at /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/lib/lwip
Pico W Wi-Fi build support available.
mbedtls available at /home/liomessi/code/pico-sdk/lib/mbedtls
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/liomessi/code/RPi_pico_tests/blink_so_complicated/build

and then
liomessi@afa:~/code/RPi_pico_tests/blink_C/build $ make blink_so_complicated
[  0%] Built target picotoolForceReconfigure
[  1%] Creating directories for 'picotoolBuild'
[  2%] No download step for 'picotoolBuild'
[  4%] No update step for 'picotoolBuild'
[  5%] No patch step for 'picotoolBuild'
[  7%] Performing configure step for 'picotoolBuild'
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
.//home/liomessi/code/RPi_pico_tests/blink_so_complicated/build/_deps/picotool/
-- Using the single-header code from /home/liomessi/code/RPi_pico_tests/blink_so_complicated/build/_deps/picotool-src/lib/nlohmann_json/single_include/
-- Found Python3: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.11.2") found components: Interpreter 
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_WFORMAT_SIGNEDNESS
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_WFORMAT_SIGNEDNESS - Success
libUSB is not found - no USB support will be built
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/liomessi/code/RPi_pico_tests/blink_so_complicated/build/_deps/picotool-build
[  8%] Performing build step for 'picotoolBuild'
[ 67%] Built target mbedcrypto
[ 75%] Built target mbedx509
[ 85%] Built target mbedtls
[ 87%] Built target errors
[ 88%] Built target elf
[ 91%] Built target bintool
[ 93%] Built target elf2uf2
[100%] Built target picotool
[ 10%] Performing install step for 'picotoolBuild'
[ 67%] Built target mbedcrypto
[ 75%] Built target mbedx509
[ 85%] Built target mbedtls
[ 87%] Built target errors
[ 88%] Built target elf
[ 91%] Built target bintool
[ 93%] Built target elf2uf2
[100%] Built target picotool
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
[ 11%] Performing test step for 'picotoolBuild'
picotool v2.0.0 (Linux, GNU-12.2.0, Release)
[ 12%] Completed 'picotoolBuild'
[ 12%] Built target picotoolBuild
[ 14%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.obj
[ 15%] Linking ASM executable bs2_default.elf
[ 15%] Built target bs2_default
[ 17%] Generating bs2_default.bin
[ 18%] Generating bs2_default_padded_checksummed.S
[ 18%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/blink_so_complicated.dir/src/main.c.obj
/home/liomessi/code/RPi_pico_tests/blink_so_complicated/src/main.c:2:10: fatal error: pico/cyw43_arch.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "pico/cyw43_arch.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/blink_so_complicated.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/blink_so_complicated.dir/src/main.c.obj] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1748: CMakeFiles/blink_so_complicated.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1755: CMakeFiles/blink_so_complicated.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:124: blink_so_complicated] Error 2

How can I solve this?

You refer to a header with a relative path ("pico/cyw43_arch.h") but it is clear from the directory structure at the top of the question that this file does not exist, so of course you get the error "pico/cyw43_arch.h: No such file or directory".

Why does that work in the examples? For example in blink.

Have you tried the full path name for "pico/cyw43_arch.h" or copied it to your build files. It is a GITHUB file, not system file.

You have to add target_link_libraries(blink_so_complicated pico_cyw43_arch_none) to your CMakeLists.txt, like this:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# initialize the SDK based on PICO_SDK_PATH
# note: this must happen before project()
include(pico_sdk_import.cmake)

project(blink_so_complicated)

# initialize the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()

# rest of your project
add_executable(blink_so_complicated
    src/main.c
)

# Add pico_stdlib library which aggregates commonly used features
target_link_libraries(blink_so_complicated pico_stdlib)
target_link_libraries(blink_so_complicated pico_cyw43_arch_none)

# create map/bin/hex/uf2 file in addition to ELF.
pico_add_extra_outputs(blink_so_complicated)


I have just figured it out with configure -DPICO_BOARD=pico_w on cmake.. and it builds fine.
